# AngularJS store an object from forEach in a Submit button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am presenting a list of Objects from an Array. Under each object there is a Submit button for that specific object. I need to store each object in its submit button. Each submit button is a call to function for that specific object.

I have two functions: c.showAllCouponsForm() and c.submitPurchaseForm()

My application needs to show all the coupons available and allow to purchase each coupon separately.

My problem is: I can successfully show all the coupons in the Array but I cannot save each object to each submit button. It saves only the last coupon in the list no matter on which submit button I click on.

**AngularJS:**

```
c.purchaseCouponResource = $resource("api/customer/getallsystemcoupons");

                c.allSystemCoupons = [];

                //Show all coupons
                c.showAllCouponsForm = function() {
                    c.allSystemCoupons = c.purchaseCouponResource.query(c.couponFields, function() {
                        c.allSystemCoupons.forEach(function(coupon){
                        c.couponFields = coupon;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv = true;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv = false;
                        })}, function() {
                            c.error("Request could not be completed")
                            c.getAllCouponsExceptionDiv = true;
                            c.getAllCouponsTableDiv = false;
                        });
                }


                c.submitPurchaseResource = $resource("api/customer/purchasecoupon");

                //Purchase a Coupon
                c.submitPurchaseForm = function() {
                    c.submitPurchaseResource.save(c.couponFields, function(coupon) {
                        c.info("Coupon Purchased Successfully")
                        c.purchaseCouponSuccessDiv = true;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv = false;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv = false;
                    }, function() {
                        c.error("Coupon Purchase Failed")
                        c.purchaseCouponSuccessDiv = false;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv = false;
                        c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv = true;
                    });
                }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-show="c.purchaseCouponDiv">
            <form ng-submit="c.showAllCouponsForm()" class="form-style-9">
                <h2>Show All Coupons</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>

            <div ng-show="c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv" ng-repeat="coupon in c.allSystemCoupons">
            <form ng-submit="c.submitPurchaseForm()" class="form-style-purchase">
                <table id="purchaseTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID: {{coupon.id}}</td>
                        <td>Title: {{coupon.title}}</td>
                        <td>Start Date: {{coupon.startDate}}</td>
                        <td>End Date: {{coupon.endDate}}</td>
                        <td>Amount: {{coupon.amount}}</td>
                        <td>Type: {{coupon.type}}</td>
                        <td>Message: {{coupon.message}}</td>
                        <td>Price: {{coupon.price}}</td>
                        <td>Image: {{coupon.image}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <ul>
                    <li class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buy Coupon" ng-bind="c.couponFields"/>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
            </div>

            <div ng-show="c.purchaseCouponSuccessDiv" id="error"><b>{{c.infoMessage}}</b></div>

            <div ng-show="c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv" id="error"><b>{{c.errorMessage}}</b></div>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be that you are binding every coupon to the same model `c.couponFields` and thats why the last always is the active one.
One solution is just to pass the current cupon in the submit function

```
<div ng-show="c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv" ng-repeat="coupon in c.allSystemCoupons">
    <form ng-submit="c.submitPurchaseForm(coupon)" class="form-style-purchase">
        <table id="purchaseTable">
            <tr>
                <td>ID: {{coupon.id}}</td>
                <td>Title: {{coupon.title}}</td>
                <td>Start Date: {{coupon.startDate}}</td>
                <td>End Date: {{coupon.endDate}}</td>
                <td>Amount: {{coupon.amount}}</td>
                <td>Type: {{coupon.type}}</td>
                <td>Message: {{coupon.message}}</td>
                <td>Price: {{coupon.price}}</td>
                <td>Image: {{coupon.image}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <ul>
            <li class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Buy Coupon"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

And then take the coupon as parameter in the submitPurchaseForm functon in the controller

```
c.submitPurchaseForm = function(coupon) {
    c.submitPurchaseResource.save(coupon, function() {
        c.info("Coupon Purchased Successfully")
        c.purchaseCouponSuccessDiv = true;
        c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv = false;
        c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv = false;
    }, function() {
        c.error("Coupon Purchase Failed")
        c.purchaseCouponSuccessDiv = false;
        c.getAllSystemCouponsTableDiv = false;
        c.getAllSystemCouponExceptionDiv = true;
    });
}
```